# To create a new column based on the joining column of two data frames using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables with columns table1 has id,name
and table2 has only id

```
table 1
--------------
id     name
--------------
1   sudheer
2   sandeep
3   suresh
----------------
```

table2

```
--------
id
-------- 
1
2
-------
```

required table should be if "id" column doesn't exist in the table2 my new column value should be "N" otherwise "Y"

```
table3

id  name        IND
1   sudheer     Y
2   sandeep     Y
3   suresh      N
```

I have tried the below steps to approach:

```
val df = hc.sql("select * from table1")
val df1 = hc.sql("select * from table2")
```

I tried to have a one more column (phone) in table2,as my join dataframe doesn't consist of id from table2,based on that null value I tried to set the value to Y/N

```
val df2 = df.join(df1,Seq("id"),"left_outer").withColumn("IND",exp(when(df1("phone")!= "null","Y").otherwise("N")))
```

But this didn't worked out with error 
found   : Boolean
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Can anyone suggest any idea how to get the required result without adding a column to my table2?

Comment: Try `withColumn("IND", when(col("phone").isNotNull, "Y").otherwise("N"))`.

Comment: I have added a phone column to my table2 and tried to achieve this...your logic worked out.

Comment: But is their anyway without adding a extra column to achieve this

Comment: The solution provided by Shankar Koirala will probably look a bit cleaner, I would suggest you to use that instead :)

Comment: Thanks Shaido  for the quick solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This you can add one new column in `table2` with default value `"Y"` and `join` and replace the `null` values with `"N"`

```
val df1 = Seq(
    (1, "sudheer"),
    (2, "sandeep"),
    (3, "suresh")
).toDF("id", "name")

val df2 = Seq(1, 2).toDF("id")
         .withColumn("IND", lit("Y"))

val df3 = df1.join(df2, Seq("id"), "left_outer")
             .na.fill("N")
```

Or you can use `when` as you did

```
val df3 = df1.join(df2, Seq("id"), "left_outer")
         .withColumn("IND", when($"IND".isNull, "N").otherwise("Y"))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: what does this command do?  val df3 = df1.join(df2,Seq("id"),"left_outer")
    .na.fill("N")

Comment: It replaces the `null` values you provide in `fill()` method.

Comment: Got it..Thanks Shankar.

Comment: Great, glad that helped you :)